# Move lxc container to a different host

Tags: lxc, move, container

Is it possible to move a lxc container from one lxc host to a different one? Here are the specs of the machines:

*Current LXC host:*

```
Gentoo: Linux 3.7.10-gentoo #1 SMP x86_64
```

*New LXC host:*

```
CentOS 6.7: Linux 2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP x86_64
```

*Container, which has to be moved:*

```
root@computername:~# cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=quantal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.10"
root@computername:~# uname -a
Linux computername.domain.tld 3.7.10-gentoo #1 SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Do any of these answers achieve what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427129/how-do-i-backup-move-lxc-containers